# REACT onclick change color of div

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, colors

I am trying to change each div's color onClick. The problem in my code is that all divs change color when one is clicked. Looking for a way to change each one's color individually

Here is my code :

```
class Main extends React.PureComponent {
state = {
    color: 'blue',
};
onChange = () => {
    this.setState({color: 'red'});
};
render() {
    return (
        <Box sx={SX.root}>
            <Box sx={SX.page}>
                <Box sx={SX.shapeContainer}>
                    <div
                        style={{backgroundColor: this.state.color, width: 20, height: 20, opacity: '50%'}}
                        onClick={this.onChange}
                    />
                    <div
                        style={{backgroundColor: this.state.color, width: 20, height: 20, opacity: '50%'}}
                        onClick={this.onChange}
                    />
                </Box>
                <MathGrid sx={SX.math1} />
            </Box>

            <Box sx={SX.header} />
            <Box sx={SX.footer} />
        </Box>
    );
}
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWSGl.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create separate component for each div with changeable colour. This way each component will have its own independently managed state. In your example, you share same color state as the rest.

`BoxComponent`

```
class BoxComponent extends React.Component {
    state = {
        color: "blue",
    };

    onChange = () => {
        this.setState({ color: "red" });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div
                style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.color, width: 20, height: 20, opacity: "50%" }}
                onClick={this.onChange}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

`MainComponent`

```
class Main extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <Box sx={SX.root}>
                <Box sx={SX.page}>
                    <Box sx={SX.shapeContainer}>
                        <BoxComponent />
                        <BoxComponent />
                    </Box>
                    <MathGrid sx={SX.math1} />
                </Box>

                <Box sx={SX.header} />
                <Box sx={SX.footer} />
            </Box>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: tried this, but only the first BoxComponent would change colors ;

Comment: do you have a codepen or something where i can check for the rest of the code?

Comment: Working now, had to swap orders of some boxes. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Both divs are using the “color” state value. You’ll need to use two separate pieces of state to manage the color of these two divs independently.

You’ll also need to either add another onChange handler, or modify the existing one to accept a color as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same state for both boxes so when you change your state - its going to change across the whole component. You will need to make separate states for each component. or create a separate component for the box

```
<div
                        style={{backgroundColor: this.state.color, width: 20, height: 20, opacity: '50%'}}
                        onClick={this.onChange}
                    />
                    <div
                        style={{backgroundColor: this.state.color, width: 20, height: 20, opacity: '50%'}}
                        onClick={this.onChange}
                    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your state variable like `${this.state.color}` in backtick.

`<div style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.color , width: 20, height: 20, opacity: "50%" }} onClick={this.onChange}></div>`